# mysqli_num_rows not working in MySQLi with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to check if there already exists a record before inserting a new one. But it doesn't work so far, here is the script:

```
<?php
session_start();
$uname = $_SESSION['username'];
$friend = $_GET["newfriend"];

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "...", "....", "...");
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die("Unable to connect to database: " . $db->connect_error);
}

$checkexist = $db->query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (username_own='$uname', username='$friend')");

//create a prepared statement
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO friends (`username_own`, `username`) VALUES (?,?)");

//bind the username and message
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $uname, $friend);

if ($checkexist->mysqli_num_rows == 0) {
  //run the query to insert the row
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: `WHERE (username_own='$uname', username='$friend')` err... that's wrong. It's either `AND` or `OR`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `INSERT IGNORE`? If there's a duplicate, it will just skip the insert.

Comment: Do be careful to prepare any and all queries that involve user data. Right here you have code so dangerously bad it could trash your entire service. Properly prepare both of these queries.

Comment: **Building SQL statements with outside variables makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.** Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like "O'Malley", will blow up your query. Learn about parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) has many detailed examples. See also http://bobby-tables.com/php for alternatives & explanation of the danger.

Comment: *"Every good answer gonna recieve a yummy cookie :)"* - I rather have a jam `$_SESSION` ♫ thank you.

Comment: `$checkexist->mysqli_num_rows` is wrong. Use `$checkexist->num_rows`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

/* Check if user exists */
$query = "SELECT count(1) FROM friends WHERE username_own=? AND username=?";

if($stmt = $db->prepare($query)){
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $uname, $friend);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($count_rows);
  $stmt->fetch();
  $stmt->close();
}else die("Failed to prepare");

/* If user doesn't exists, insert */
if($count_row == 0){

    $query = "INSERT INTO friends (`username_own`, `username`) VALUES (?,?)";

    if($stmt = $db->prepare($query)){
      $stmt->bind_param('ss', $uname, $friend);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->close();
    }else die("Failed to prepare!");
}
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- oops I meant to change that

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. Another thing though, it's hard to say whether OP wants to check for both or either. So it could also be an `OR`. But, we'll wait to see what OP has to say, *cheers*

Comment: @Arian There were some little mistakes in your script but now it works :) Thanks! For future readers, could you please delete this line: `$stmt->bind_param()` and add a semicolon here: `$stmt->close();` Here is the cookie 0 =)

Comment: @mmibm I took care of it, thanks for pointing that out. Can I have a cookie too? ;-)

Comment: @Fred -ii- Of course you can have one - Here is the cookie O

Comment: Thanks for the cookie, thanks @Fred-ii- for fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//create a prepared statement
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO friends (`username_own`, `username`) VALUES (?,?)");

//bind the username and message
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $uname, $friend);

if ($checkexist->mysqli_num_rows == 0 || $checkexist->mysqli_num_rows <> 0) {
  //run the query to insert the row
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: You wrote `if ($checkexist->mysqli_num_rows == 0 || $checkexist->mysqli_num_rows <> 0)`. Why not just use `if(true)` as it would have the same result (of course, so would removing the if block).

Answer (score 0):

`$checkexist->mysqli_num_rows` is wrong. It's just

```
$checkexist->num_rows
```

or you can use

```
mysqli_num_rows($checkexist)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Replace most of your code with a simple `INSERT IGNORE ...` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`.

The latter lets you change columns if the record already exists (based on any PRIMARY or UNIQUE key(s)).